# adding objects to vector in different method android

Tags: android, arrays, vector

The application is supposed to add a 3 if the user presses a button with a number 3 on it, and same thing with 1. When it hits close it is supposed to display all the numbers in the exact order they were pressed. Im stuck because im trying to save the numbers in a vector that is supposed to grow, but im not able to add an element to the vector with .add() or .addElement()  when they are in different methods, I would appreciate any help on how to add this elements and make the vector grow, and any suggestion on how to print the numbers on a textView, and maybe a different storage way? Thank you, here's my code:

```
package com.example.holamundo;

import java.util.Vector;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Mesa1_1 extends MainActivity {
int counter=0,countrojopar=0,countrojoimpar=0,countnegropar=0;
    int countnegroimpar=0,hotness=1;
int[] numregist;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.mesa11);

    ;
}

public void CambiarValorBoton1(View view){                //DESDE AQUI ROJO IMPAR//
    Vector datanum = new Vector();
    datanum.add(1);
    }
public void CambiarValorBoton3(View view){
    datanum.addElement(3);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare the Vector as an instance variable.

```
public class Mesa1_1 extends MainActivity {
int counter=0,countrojopar=0,countrojoimpar=0,countnegropar=0;
    int countnegroimpar=0,hotness=1; Vector datanum;
int[] numregist; 
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.mesa11);
datanum = new Vector();
;
}

public void CambiarValorBoton1(View view){                //DESDE AQUI ROJO IMPAR//

datanum.add(1);
}
public void CambiarValorBoton3(View view){
datanum.addElement(3);
}
```